# What are all the ways that a SELECT statement could be made to not terminate or take a *very* long time?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

One way is using `WITH RECURSIVE`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  t AS (
    SELECT 1 n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1 FROM t
  )
  SELECT * FROM t;
```

Joins can be made to return a lot of rows from even small tables.

Tables themselves could be huge.

Views can be done with any such `SELECT` statement and so `SELECT` statements that use them may also not terminate.

Is that it? If `SELECT` statements did not have `WITH RECURSIVE` syntax, could not do arbitrary joins, were limited to small tables or hard a small `LIMIT` enforced, and could not use any such view, would they all be guaranteed to terminate in a reasonable time*?

I'm particularly interested in MariaDB/MySQL.

I'm thinking of making a new language based on SQL's `SELECT` statements that transpiles/compiles to SQL and I'm wondering what I can do to guarantee query termination in reasonable time*.

<sub>* What's reasonable time is of course subjective. I just mention it to exclude queries that are set to terminate in a time frame so long that we may as well treat it as non-terminating.</sub>

Comment: don't most connection drivers have timeout settings to prevent long running queries from happening?  If you want to *cause* a timeout, you can always just do multiple cross joins on large tables (or multiple small ones) and blow your estimated result set.  I caught a developer with a 9TB estimated size query because of a bad cross join....

Comment: @JonathanFite Yes, at least MariaDB does like Rick mentioned, and I also mentioned being able to do it using joins in the question. I'd still like to know if there are other ways.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB-10.1.1 has `max_statement_time` to abort long-running statements.  I don't think MySQL has anything equivalent.

(Of course, you need at least 10.2 to get Recursive CTEs.)

Comment: Thank you. That's good to know, but I'd rather not have to rely on setting an arbitrary time limit like that.

Comment: [cte_max_recursion_depth](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_cte_max_recursion_depth) / [max_recursive_iterations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_recursive_iterations) might help to define reasonableness

Comment: That assumes that recursive depth is the problem.  One CTE I was looking at effectively turned a simple loop into recursion.  So, what would have been a fast 10K loop became a 10K-deep recursion.  Performance nightmare.